# Allow user to strikethrough cells within table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to allow user input to strikethrough certain cells within a table. For example, if we have this simple table displayed in Shiny:

[image: simple_gpa_table_orig]

The user can select a single cell which would cause the text/formatting within the cell to include strikethrough. If the user selected Josh Barry's GPA, the table would update to:

[image: simple_gpa_table_updated]

Is there a way to do this and for R Shiny to recognize which cells have the strikethrough applied?

I know there exists packages like `rhandsontable` but couldn't determine any strikethrough functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way with **DT**:

```r
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'tbody', function(e) {",
  "  const td = e.target.closest('td');",
  "  if(!td) {return;} // Quit, not clicked on a cell",
  "  const row = td.parentElement;",
  "  const i = row.rowIndex - 1;",
  "  const j = td.cellIndex;",
  "  var cell = table.cell(i, j);",
  "  const cellData = cell.data();",
  "  cell.data('<s>' + cellData + '</s>').draw();",
  "});"
)

dat <- iris[1:5, ]

datatable(
  dat, 
  callback = JS(callback)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is so cool! I haven't utilized callbacks as much so will definitely be exploring a ton more there. A couple follow-ups: Can you build a reactive action based on if a user were to strike through? Can you determine if a cell has the strikethrough formatting?

Comment: @figNewton   I don't understand your first question. Regarding the second one, a cell has a strikethrough if its content is enclosed between `<s>` and `</s>`.